# Update ParentId of Records Where Three Conditions Met on SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table named `Folders`. In this table some of the folders have their `ParentID` set to 0. I want to move those folder into a folder named `Archives`.

The `Archives` folder will be parent for these folders. But the folders I want to archive must be older than 2015. And they should not contain another parent.

I'm looking to change `ParentID` of folders if following conditions are met:

1. `Project ID = 100`
2. Created Date < Before 2015-01-01
3. `ParentID = 0`

I'm trying this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Folders
WHERE ProjectID = 100 
  AND CAST (CreateDate AS DATE) < '2015-01-01'

EXCEPT 

SELECT *
FROM Folders
WHERE ProjectID = 100 AND ParentID > 0;
```

I think using the above query for selecting records fine, but how can i use the update statement on result?

Btw the query above will also list Archives folder but I can edit it's Parent Folder after updating all records.

Any ideas?

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for helping on content of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this SQL query should also return the proper rows - correct?

```
SELECT *
FROM Folders
WHERE ProjectID = 100 
  AND CAST (CreateDate AS DATE) < '2015-01-01'
  AND ParentID = 0;
```

(*why are you casting `CreatedDate` as a `DATE`? What datatype is it? Shouldn't it **already** be a `DATE` anyway??*)

If so, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) based on this query to update the table:

```
DECLARE @ArchiveFolder INT = 99999; // or whatever it is

;WITH RowsToUpdate AS
(
    SELECT PrimaryKeyColumn
    FROM dbo.Folders
    WHERE ProjectID = 100 
      AND CAST (CreateDate AS DATE) < '2015-01-01'
      AND ParentID = 0;
)
UPDATE f
SET ParentID = @ArchiveFolder
FROM dbo.Folders f
INNER JOIN RowsToUpdate upd ON f.PrimaryKeyColumn = upd.PrimaryKeyColumn
```

Basically, the CTE selects the **primary key** of your table to update, for those rows that match all your criteria - and the following `UPDATE` statement then updates those rows in the `Folders` table that are in that list of primary keys.

Comment: Can't CTEs can be updated directly?  No need for the self join?

Comment: @marc_s Current DataType for CreatedDate is datetime, that's why I wanted to cast it as date.